# Render component in different container on button click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm using React and React Router to build a web app. Currently, the header is is it's own component, and is loaded into the HomePage container with a Page component. I want to render a new component on click of a button in the header inside the page component

This is the mainpage container I have right now

```
import React from 'react';
import Page1 from './Page1';
import Page2 from './Page2';
import Page3 from './Page3';
import Page4 from "./Page4";
import {Header} from "../components/Header";

export default class MAINHome extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Header/>
                <Page1/>
                <Page2/>
                <Page3/>
                <Page4/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

```
            <div id="header" className="container-fluid">

                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-md-4" id="logo-col">
                        <img src={require("../assets/LOGO.png")} alt=""/>
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-md-8 d-flex justify-content-end" id="nav-col">
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <Link to="/trees" id="trees-adopted-nav">
                                    300+ TREES ADOPTED
                                </Link>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#" className="about-us">
                                    ABOUT US
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#" className="about-trees">
                                    ABOUT TREES
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#" className="contact-us">
                                    CONTACT US
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <Route path="/trees" exact="exact" component={AdoptTrees} />
                </div>

            </div>
        </Router>
```

This renders a component inside the header itself, but I want it to render instead of the entire main page itself by replacing

```
<div>
     <Header/>
     <Page1/>
     <Page2/>
     <Page3/>
     <Page4/>
</div>
```

Comment: I have no idea what Page1...Page4 are, but I'd bet good money that you just duplicated a file four times, when what you really needed was a single Page component, with `<Page pageNumber={2}>...</Page>`handling. That said, looking at how you're using `<Route>` you probably want to reread the tutorials on React-Router, because that's not how you declare your routes. It might be where you put a `<Link>`, but it's definitely not where `<Route>` goes.

Comment: Please could you rephrase your question?